# Symlink not working when pointing one subfolder to a sibling subfolder

Tags: symlink, shared-hosting, jail-shell

Trying to create a symlink in my hostgator shared hosting account via Jailshell 4.1 and my Mac's Terminal as a test before applying the symlinks to a larger project.

When I try the following it doesn't seem to work:

```
ln -s public_html/y public_html/x
```

As I get the following response:

```
ln: creating symbolic link `public_html/x/y': Permission denied
```

I am simply trying to set it up so that going to `public_html/x` will instead take me to `public_html/y`. My ultimate goal is to later configure many wordpress sites to share a single set of core files without sharing databases, as described here:

http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/wordpress-multitenancy/
http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/updated-wordpress-multitenancy/

Edit: Both folders `/x` and `/y` already exist, containing a simple index file in each.

Comment: You can't create a symlink with the same name as an already existing directory. That's why it's trying to create it as a child of directory `x`. Furthermore, it seems you don't have write permission on that directory, which is why it's failing to create it.

Comment: Ah! This makes sense. I've deleted the `/x` folder and moved `/y` into a subfolder `/z` which has 777 permissions. I've also given `/y` 777 permissions but I still get the following:

`ln: creating symbolic link 'public_html/z/x': Permission denied`

when I use

`ln -s public_html/z/y public_html/z/x`